# Pymongo: How to check if the update was successful ?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to check if the update was successful in Pymongo? If the record was updated with the same value it should be considered a successful update. ie, Even if the modified count is zero it is considered a successful update. How to do this.

```
result = _db.testcollection.update_one({"_id": col_id}, {"$set": obj})
return True if result.modified_count > 0 else False
```

This works well if the value is changed. But I want to return true even when technically the record was not changed because the record is same what we are trying to update.

How to do this?

Comment: So… what exactly constitutes a *failure*…?

Comment: When the condition did not match to update or could not be updated due to any other exceptions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The below solution worked for me. Check matched_count instead of modified_count. If there were a matched records and no exception it means that it is successful.

```
try:
    result = _db.testcollection.update_one({"_id": col_id}, {"$set": obj})
    return result.matched_count > 0 
except:pymongo.errors.PyMongoError as e:
    return False
```